# TweenMax trying to animate one character at time on text field

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gsap

This is my html code:

```
   <h1 id="designs">
      <span>D</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span>s</span>
      <span>i</span>
      <span>g</span>
      <span>n</span>
      <span>s</span>
   </h1>
```

And I am trying to tween each letter to rotate in like so:

```
TweenMax.staggerFromTo($map.designs.find('span'), 1, {
    rotationY: 180
}, {
    rotationY: 0
}, 0.1);
```

This is not working! Although doing the exact same thing but instead modifying the top/left/right/bottom/opacity/etc.. values works.

Please give me a hand as to why I cannot modify the 3d values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My modified version works, and I've included a jsfiddle for you to check, I also added the following css which seems to be needed for Chrome, at least in jsfiddle.

```
span { display: inline-block; }

TweenMax.staggerFromTo($('#designs').children(), 5, {
    rotationY: 180
}, {
    rotationY: 0
}, 0.1);
```

See this fiddle to show it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/SERT5/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately with some fonts display: inline-block on the letters causes clipping.. I guess that is just a browser issue

Comment: Maybe try display block float left?